# Getting specific column value using eloquent ORM and printing in view Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to get a specific column value from the DB and pass it to the view and print it.

```
  $profile = new Profile();
  $profile_name = $profile
  ->where('id',$id)
  ->get(['profile_name']);
  return view('profile_page')->with('profile_name',$profile_name);
```

In my view

```
<span class="profile_name"> &nbsp;&nbsp;{{$profile_name}}</span>
```

The above gets me the value `[{"profile_name":"Frontend Dev"}]`. I want to print only `Frontend Dev` in my view. I know with `foreach` i can do this. is there any other simpler way to do this ?

Comment: Change `<span class="profile_name"> &nbsp;&nbsp;{{$profile_name}}</span>` with `<span class="profile_name"> &nbsp;&nbsp;{{$profile_name->profile_name}}</span>` and that should do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pluck()` and first()` methods:

```
$profile_name = Profile::where('id', $id)->pluck('profile_name')->first()->profile_name;
```

But usually it's a good idea to get profile instead:

```
$profile = Profile::find($id);
```

And print data in a view:

```
{{ $profile->profile_name }}
```

Comment: Just a side note, and probably has nothing to do with this (since you only want the profile_name for one profile). But you could use Laravel 5.4s new collection shortcut. Let's say you would like to get the profile_name for every profiles you have, you could do $profile->map->profile_name;

Which is pretty sweet for quickly accessing attributes on collections!

https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-4/episodes/2